# `git pull` doesn't merge, but `git pull origin <branch-name>` does, why?

Tags: git

And it's like that for all branches. Looks like `git pull` stopped merging my current branch with the latest remote for some reason. It must be some configuration issue? When I do `git pull origin <branch-name>` then everything works as expected.

Note that when I did `git st` I got the following:

```
$ git st
On branch <name>
Your branch is behind 'origin/<name>' by 139 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

So it seems the branch is tracked properly. But then `git pull` didn't update the branch.

Comment: What is the output of `git pull`?

Comment: `git pull` is configurable. How did you configure it, if you did configure it? What is your `git st` alias—is it just `st = status`, or is it something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` combines a  `git fetch` and  `git merge`.

There are three levels of configuration for default `pull` behavior:

- `pull.rebase` which is equivalent to  `git pull --rebase` (combine a series of commits to a new base commit):

When `true` (`git config branch.master.rebase true`) rebase branches on top of the fetched branch, instead of **merging** the default branch from the default

- `branch.autosetuprebase` (`git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always`):

When a new branch is created with `git branch` or `git checkout` that tracks another branch, this variable tells Git to set up pull to **rebase** instead of **merge**  When never, rebase is never automatically set to true. When local, rebase is set to true for tracked branches of other local branches. When remote, rebase is set to true for tracked branches of remote-tracking branches. When always, rebase will be set to true for all tracking branches. See "branch.autoSetupMerge" for details on how to set up a branch to track another branch. This option defaults to never.

- `branch.<branchname>.rebase`:

When true, rebase the branch  on top of the fetched branch, instead of merging the default branch from the default remote when "git pull" is run.

As a side `git config --help` is your friend.

Comment: The thing here is, setting up to use `git merge` would have run `git merge`; setting up to use `git rebase` would have run `git rebase`; either way the result would be that the current branch would meet up with, or be one ahead of, the upstream, which appears to be `origin/<name>`. So we're left with a bit of a mystery here. I do have a vague guess or two but I'm waiting for more information from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The less verbose `git pull` uses the [default settings](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_default_behaviour).

`git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch origin && git merge origin/<upstream>`, while the verbose `git pull origin master` pulls changes from the remote `master`, and merge them to your current branch.

Comment: I feel like this would make more sense if you used `<upstream>` instead of `master`. And then explained the difference.